# Как парсить несколько фотографий/видео в одном посте в инстаграме на python?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хочу извлечь линки всех изображений с ссылки, но у меня возникла проблема с извлечением информации с тега `script`

Код вот:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re

# Ссылка на полную страницу
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B5n2EXjF_1C/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script', attrs={'type':"text/javascript"}, text=re.compile('window._sharedData'))
data = json.loads(script.next)
image_url = data['display_url']

print(image_url)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Desktop/test/venv/Test.py", line 19, in data = json.loads(script.next) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Не сильно умею работать с типами `js`, но если есть у кого-то желание и время помочь,буду вам очень признателен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменения:

- Вместо `script.next` использовал `script.text`
- Добавил в регулярку правила захвата куска js
- Добавил извлечение куска js (`search(...).group(1)`)

Попробуйте:

```
import datetime as DT
import json
import re
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN = re.compile('window._sharedData = ({.+});')

# Ссылка на полную страницу
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B5n2EXjF_1C/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script', attrs={'type':"text/javascript"}, text=JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN)
print(script)
# <script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_tok ...

print(script.text)
# window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"RtSXgxK6b0Lh4Ag3wSFRebLUfdJRA9qc","viewer":null, ...

# FIX: Если script имеет содержимое, а script.text возвращает пустую строку, то 
# в регулярку можно отдавать str(script), т.е.: JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN.search(str(script))
# В bs4 версии 4.7.1 проблемы не было, а в 4.9.1 уже есть
m = JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN.search(script.text)
if not m:
    print(f'Not found "window._sharedData = "!')
    sys.exit()

shared_data_text = m.group(1)
print(shared_data_text)
# {"config":{"csrf_token":"RtSXgxK6b0Lh4Ag3wSFRebLUfdJRA9qc","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code": ...

data = json.loads(shared_data_text)
print(data)
# {'config': {'csrf_token': 'RtSXgxK6b0Lh4Ag3wSFRebLUfdJRA9qc', 'viewer': None, 'viewerId': None}, 'country_code': ...
```

Я бы еще добавил дамп html, что не прошли проверку, это полезно для разбора ошибок, например:

```
import datetime as DT
...

m = JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN.search(script.text)
if not m:
    file_name_dump = str(DT.datetime.now()).replace(':', '') + '.html'
    with open(file_name_dump, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(rs.content)
    print(f'Not found "window._sharedData = ", see: {file_name_dump}!')
    sys.exit()
```

---

Без `bs4`:

```
import datetime as DT
import json
import re
import sys
import requests

JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN = re.compile('window._sharedData = ({.+});')

# Ссылка на полную страницу
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B5n2EXjF_1C/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

m = JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN.search(r.text)
if not m:
    print(f'Not found "window._sharedData = "!')
    sys.exit()
print(shared_data_text)

data = json.loads(shared_data_text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Не запускается
Вот ошибка:
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/paras/Desktop/test/venv/Test.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = json.loads(shared_data_text)
  File "C:\Users\paras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

Comment: @ShevchukAndry, странно, у меня все работает. Вы точно полностью скопировали мой код? Вообще, я добавил вывод в консоль каждого шага, посмотрите что у вас пошло не так. Вывод должен быть похожим на тот, что я в коде описал

Comment: Все скопировал правильно,но всеравно не работает
Я хотел спарсить все изображения доступные в посте,но я как уже понял,Выбрал не очень правильный путь,не знаете можно ли как-то по другому попробовать вытянуть те линки изображений?

Comment: @ShevchukAndry, а какая ошибка у вас? Случаем не `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. Для парсинга инстаграмма можно посмотреть в сторону selenium

Comment: @ShevchukAndry, возможно, instagram начал вас блокировать, поэтому по той ссылке выдавалась какая-нибудь заглушка. Нужно смотреть что `requests` вернул (например в файл записать), а так я могу предложить вариант без html парсер (посмотрите в ответе), и... нужно проверять что возвращает `search`, это тоже в ответ добавлю

Comment: @ShevchukAndry, добавил проверку результата регулярки и простенький дампер html, что не прошли проверку -- для анализа проблемы

Comment: @ShevchukAndry, нашел интересную вещь... У меня bs4 версии 4.7.1 (`import bs4; print(bs4.__version__)`), запустил код из ответа в online ide (https://repl.it/repls/ButterySpiritedLinuxpc) там bs4 имеет версию 4.9.1 и у него `script.text` ничего не возвращает, но `print(script)` выводит тег, это очень похоже на ошибку. Чтобы это обойти нужно вместо `script.text` использовать `str(script)`, например: `JS_SHARED_DATA_PATTERN.search(str(script))`

Comment: да вы самый искренний и добрый человек на подобных форумах,СПАСИБО ВАМ ПРОСТО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!
и хотел спросить по поводу того чтобы парсить через selenium,если потом бота хостить на сервер,как это повлияет на производительность бота?
Если же вы не имеете ответа на этот вопрос,то ничего страшного,вы и так мне сильно помогли

Comment: @ShevchukAndry, пожалуйста :) Если мой ответ полезный, отметьте его (стрелка вверх) и примите (галочка), это слева от ответа. Я не хостил ботов, но по идеи, самая большая нагрузка будет от селениума, а тот по сути тот же браузер. А браузеры могут кучу памяти сожрать, т.к. сайты содержат много мультимедиа. Но можно облегчить нагрузку, например сделав селениум невидимым (headless) и например убрав загрузку картинок (наверняка и с css можно что-нибудь сделать). В гугле полно инфы по селениуму, особенно на английском стеке